Python multiprocessing: Exponential slowdown when processing batches of HDF5 files
I'm trying to load and process large amounts of HDF5 files using Python and convert them into dataframes. The HDF5 files are scattered in equal-sized batches. I've tried two approaches using multiprocessing, but both are experiencing exponential slowdown with each batch. Here's my current architecture:
Using multiprocessing.Pool:
result = []
for batch in batches:
    paths = get_batch_paths(batch)
    with mp.Pool(n_jobs) as pool:
        for res in tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(process_h5, paths)):
            result.append(res)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()


Using joblib:
result = []
for batch in batches:
    paths = get_batch_paths(batch)
    parallel = joblib.Parallel(n_jobs)
    data = parallel(delayed(process_h5)(path) for path in tqdm(paths))
    result.extend(data)
    parallel._backend.terminate()

What I'm observing is that each iteration of batches becomes exponentially slower, starting with about a minute for the first batch and almost doubling with each subsequent batch. Each batch contains approximately 1000 file paths. My questions are:

Is this slowdown due to frequent construction and termination of workers? I would have thought this inefficiency would result in a constant overhead for each iteration, not an increasing one.
Could this be I/O related, since len(paths) ~ 1000 results in many parallel I/O operations opening and closing HDF5 files?
How can I optimize this process to maintain consistent performance across batches?

Any insights or suggestions for improvement would be greatly appreciated.

A few suggestions: 1. Observe system memory usage. 2. Run something like perf top or a profiler to try and narrow the issue down. 3. Switch the order of batches to ensure that it's not simply data related

"Could this be I/O related" On linux you can easily check this with iotop (not installed by default though and it requires root privileges). Also please note each process worker you not have any work outside the main section (i.e. if __name__ == '__main__' block). Otherwise they will probably execute it, and if this work consists in running multiprocessing operations, things, then it's going to smell bad ;)

What is the value of n_jobs? How many CPUs do you have available? These values are crucial. If n_jobs is higher than the number of available CPUs then you're asking for trouble.
